# Cmd and exclamation marks - Part II

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, delayedvariableexpansion

I'm really wondering why my string replacement procedure works when parsing text files containing any special characters including exclamation marks. I expected that delayed variable expansion would switch off special meaning of ampersand, percent sign etc. but will fail instead for exclamation marks...

Code:

```
@echo on & setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS

set "InFile=%~1"
set "OutFile=%~2"
set "Replace=%~3"

CALL :ParseCue "%%InFile%%" "%%OutFile%%" "%%Replace%%"

endlocal &GOTO:EOF

:ParseCue
@echo on & setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set "FileToParse=%~1"
set "OutputFile=%~2"
set "NewExtension=%~3"
for /F "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%a in ("%FileToParse%") DO (
  set "line=%%a"
  @echo on & setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
  set "line=!line:.wav=%NewExtension%!"
  echo(!line!>>"%OutputFile%"
  endlocal
)
endlocal &GOTO:EOF
```

InputFile.txt:

```
This a test for parsing lines with special characters
Rock & Roll.wav
Rock & Roll!.wav
Special | < > ~ \ ²³ { [ ] } ! " ´ ' ` üäö @ ; : € $ % & / ( ) = ? chars.wav
```

Command line syntax:

```
D:\Users\Public\Batch\YAET>parse.bat "InputFile.txt" "OutputFile.txt" ".flac"
```

OutputFile.txt:

```
This a test for parsing lines with special characters
Rock & Roll.flac
Rock & Roll!.flac
Special | < > ~ \ ²³ { [ ] } ! " ´ ' ` üäö @ ; : € $ % & / ( ) = ? chars.flac
```

---

**EDIT / Supplement:**

After 1 1/2 years I had to use this code snippet again. See two additional examples handling poison chars. First one with temporary enabled delayed expansion again (see Ansgars answer), second one using `CALL`. Both will parse path and name of non-empty files in and below current directory, but without trailing drive letter and path to current dir.

Example #1 (Enclosing double quotes in `set "File=!File..."` and `echo "!FILE!">>...` are not required):

```
@echo off & setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
del NonEmptyFiles.txt >NUL 2>&1
echo Searching non-empty files in and below current directory ...
for /f "tokens=*" %%I in ('dir /s /b /a:-D') do (
    if not %%~zI==0 (
        set "File=%%I"
        setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
        set "File=!File:%cd%\=!"
        echo "!File!">> NonEmptyFiles.txt
        endlocal
        )
    )
echo Done. See NonEmptyFiles.txt.
endlocal &goto:EOF
```

Example #2 (slower, enclosing double quotes required):

```
@echo off & setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
del NonEmptyFiles.txt >NUL 2>&1
echo Searching non-empty files in and below current directory ...
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('dir /s /b /a:-D') do (
    if not %%~zi==0 (
        set "File=%%i"
        call set "File=%%File:%cd%\=%%"
        call echo "%%File%%">> NonEmptyFiles.txt
        )
    )
echo Done. See NonEmptyFiles.txt.
endlocal &goto:EOF
```

Files and folders for testing:

```
D:\Martin\Any & Path>dir /s /b /a:-D
D:\Martin\Any & Path\Hello! World!.txt
D:\Martin\Any & Path\Rock & Roll\!File! !!File!!.txt
D:\Martin\Any & Path\Rock & Roll\%File% %%File%% %%I.txt
D:\Martin\Any & Path\Rock & Roll\Poison! !§$%&()=`´'_;,.-#+´^ßöäüÖÄÜ°^^#.txt
D:\Martin\Any & Path\Rock & Roll\SizeZero.txt
```

Output:

```
D:\Martin\Any & Path>stringinforloop.bat
Searching non-empty files in and below current directory ...
See NonEmptyFiles.txt. Done.

D:\Martin\Any & Path>type NonEmptyFiles.txt
"Hello! World!.txt"
"Rock & Roll\!File! !!File!!.txt"
"Rock & Roll\%File% %%File%% %%I.txt"
"Rock & Roll\Poison! !§$%&()=`´'_;,.-#+´^ßöäüÖÄÜ°^^#.txt"
```

Enjoy batching! Martin

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's because you enable delayed expansion *after* `set "line=%%a"`:

```
set "line=%%a"
@echo on & setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set "line=!line:.wav=%NewExtension%!"
```

If you enable delayed expansion *before* assigning `%%a`:

```
@echo on & setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set "line=%%a"
set "line=!line:.wav=%NewExtension%!"
```

you'll get

> Special | < > ~ \ ²³ { [ ] } € $ % & / ( ) = ? chars.flac

instead of

> Special | < > ~ \ ²³ { [ ] } ! " ´ ' ` üäö @ ; : € $ % & / ( ) = ? chars.flac

---

**Edit:** Delayed expansion controls when variables in a statement are expanded. The critical statement in your script is the line

```
set "line=%%a"
```

which assigns the value of the loop variable `%%a` to the variable `line`. With delayed expansion disabled the literal value of `%%a` is assigned, because the script interpreter cannot expand `%%a` at parse time. However, when you enable delayed expansion, bang-variables are expanded at execution time, so the interpreter looks at the value of `%%a` and expands any `!whatever!` in it before the result is assigned to the variable `line`.

Perhaps it'll become clearer with an example. If you add a line

> %foo% !foo!

to the input file and define the variable in the script:

```
@echo on & setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS

set "foo=bar"
set "InFile=%~1"
...
```

When you enable delayed expansion *after* `set "line=%%a"` neither `%foo%` nor `!foo!` are expanded before `%%a` is assigned to the variable `line` (the interpreter doesn't see the value of `%%a` before execution time), so you get this output:

> %foo% !foo!

When you enable delayed expansion *before* `set "line=%%a"` the interpreter will expand bang-variables before assigning the result to the variable `line`, so you get this output:

> %foo% bar

`%foo%` would only be expanded at parse time, at which point the interpreter cannot see the actual value of `%%a`, so `%foo%` remains a literal `%foo%` here.

Further assignments like `set "line=!line:.wav=%NewExtension%!"` don't affect bangs or percent signs inside a variable, because expansion isn't transitive, i.e. it translates `!line!` to `%foo% bar` (or `%foo% !foo!`) and then stops.

You can force the expansion of (percent-)variables inside variables with the `call` command, though. A command `call set "line=!line!"` first expands to `call set "line=%foo% bar"` in the current context, and then `call` evaluates `set "line=%foo% bar"` in a new context where `%foo%` is expanded to `bar` as well, so the variable `line` is assigned the value `bar bar`.

---

Just as a side note: your code is way too complicated. You'd get the exact same results with this:

```
set "FileToParse=%~1"
set "OutputFile=%~2"
set "NewExtension=%~3"
for /F "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%a in ("%FileToParse%") DO (
  set "line=%%a"
  @setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
  set "line=!line:.wav=%NewExtension%!"
  echo(!line!>>"%OutputFile%"
  endlocal
)
```

Comment: Could you explain how line is expanded with enabled delayed expansion then? I do not get why string is cropped like this when assigning %%a within new local environment. Thanks! And code is somehow complex because it is just a snipped of a script where I need it as a subroutine. Martin