# Remove lines until i find a particular line in text file using batch script

Tags: batch-file, text-files

I have a text file as below:

```
This is a sample file
some dummy text 
some dummy text
some dummy text
I don't know how many times this some dummy text above me is repeated
I need only the lines starting from here SOME IMP TEXT
SOME IMP TEXT
SOME IMP TEXT
I don't know how many times this SOME IMP TEXT above and below me is repeated
SOME IMP TEXT
I need it till I find this line SOME IMP TEXT
some dummy text
some dummy text
I don't know how many times this some dummy text above me is repeated
```

I need a file which has only the lines from "**I need only the lines starting from here SOME IMP TEXT**" till the find "**I need text till I find this line SOME IMP TEXT**" (Both the bold lines inclusive). Nothing but I need below:

```
I need only the lines starting from here SOME IMP TEXT
SOME IMP TEXT
SOME IMP TEXT
I don't know how many times this SOME IMP TEXT above and below me is repeated
SOME IMP TEXT
I need it till I find this line SOME IMP TEXT
```

Comment: You might be interested in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33641615)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [**tailhead.bat**](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/fileUtils/tailHead.bat) - it can to show a file content from certain line to a another line by number.If you have the tailHead.bat you can:

```
@echo off
::==========================
:: 
set file=text.txt
set "line1=I need only the lines starting from here SOME IMP TEXT"
set "line2=I need it till I find this line SOME IMP TEXT"
::========================
for /f "tokens=1 delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /n /c:"%line1%" "%file%"') do set "l1=%%a"
for /f "tokens=1 delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /n /c:"%line2%" "%file%"') do set "l2=%%a"

::echo %l1%
::echo %l2%

tailhead.bat -file=text.txt -begin=%l1% -end=%l2%
```

this will include the lines. if you want to exclude them you can increase the begin line and decrease the end line with `set /a`