# Batch Script to Write One specific part of a file to a consolidated Output File

Tags: for-loop, batch-file

I have a folder with a lot of sub-directories, each with a .diff file that I want to perform a search in for a specific string using a batch script. Because of our IT requirements, I do not have access to powershell. I am trying to search for a specific string in the .diff file, and summarize if it is found or not a summary file. This part I have working using this script, thanks to another user on this site:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

REM Set the path to the folder containing subdirectories
SET folderPath=%~dp0

REM Set the specific string to search for at the beginning of a line
SET "searchString"="COMPARE DIFFERENCE FOUND AT"

REM Set the next string to search for indicating the end of content to copy
SET "endString"="EXTRA DATA SKIPPED ON TEST FILE"

REM Set the path for the output file to save the result
SET "outputFile=%folderPath%ValidationSummary.csv"
SET "output_fail=%folderPath%Validation_Fail.out"

REM Initialize a variable to track whether the start search string is found
SET "startStringFound=0"

REM Clear output file for first run
ECHO Run Name, Status > "%outputFile%"
TYPE NUL > "%output_fail%"

REM Loop through each subdirectory in the specified folder
FOR /r "%folderPath%" %%f in (*.diff) do (
    REM Initialize variables
    set "found=0"
    set "copying=0"
    set "matchingLine="

    REM Read each line from the file and process content between searchString and endString
    for /f "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /i /l /b /c:" COMPARE DIFFERENCE FOUND AT" "%%f"') do (
            if not defined matchingLine set "matchingLine=%%a"
    )
    if defined matchingLine (
    echo %%~nxf, Failed >> "%outputFile%"
    ) else (
    echo %%~nxf, Passed >> "%outputFile%"
    )
)
```

I would now like to try to copy the contents of the files where this string is found to a certain stopping point in a consolidated output file for quicker checking. Based on the responses from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33638832/batch-file-find-two-lines-then-copy-everything-between-those-lines), I came up with the following but now the files aren't being flagged for the "failed" output.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

REM Set the path to the folder containing subdirectories
SET folderPath=%~dp0

REM Set the specific string to search for at the beginning of a line
SET "searchString"="COMPARE DIFFERENCE FOUND AT"

REM Set the next string to search for indicating the end of content to copy
SET "endString"="EXTRA DATA SKIPPED ON TEST FILE"

REM Set the path for the output file to save the result
SET "outputFile=%folderPath%ValidationSummary.csv"
SET "output_fail=%folderPath%Validation_Fail.out"

REM Initialize a variable to track whether the start search string is found
SET "startStringFound=0"

REM Clear output file for first run
ECHO Run Name, Status > "%outputFile%"
TYPE NUL > "%output_fail%"

REM Loop through each subdirectory in the specified folder
FOR /r "%folderPath%" %%f in (*.diff) do (
    REM Initialize variables
    set "found=0"
    set "copying=0"
    set "matchingLine="
    set "startLine="
    set "endLine="

    REM Read each line from the file and process content between searchString and endString
    for /f "tokens=1,* delims=" %%a in ('findstr /nilbc:" COMPARE DIFFERENCE FOUND AT" "%%f"') do (
            if not defined startLine set "startLine=%%a" & set "matchingLine=%%b"
    )
    for /f "tokens=1,* delims=" %%c in ('findstr /nilbc:" BOTTOM OF GOOD FILE" "%%f"') do (
    if not defined endLine set "endLine=%%c"
    )
    if defined matchingLine (
    echo %%~nxf, Failed >> "%outputFile%"
    for /f "tokens=1,* delims=" %%L in ("%%f") do (
        set LINE=%%L
            if !LINE!=="!endLine!" (set start=0)
        if !start! equ 1 (echo !line! >> "%output_fail%")
        if !LINE!=="!startLine!" (set start=1)
    )
    ) else (
    echo %%~nxf, Passed >> "%outputFile%"
    )
)
```

I think I am misunderstanding the %%variable and am not sure how to correct this.

Answer (score 0):

Your first question "Find the line number of a certain line" was misleading.

Of course, you can find the line numbers of a startstring and an endstring and reprocess the file with "if currentlinenumber is between startstringline and endstringline then print the line", but that means, reading each file several times, which is time consuming.

Better parse each file just one time, start printing when you hit the startline and stop printing when you hit the endline. I used flags for tracking that (sort of "binary variables" - defined or not defined - their actual value when defined is not important) - `flag` to track if we are inside a desired text block and `found` to know if we already found the text block, so we are able to only output the first occurrence and ignore any further occurrences. When the file is completely processed and `found` is still not defined, we know there is no matching text block.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "folderpath=."

(FOR /r "%folderPath%" %%f in (*.diff) do (
    REM Initialize variables
    set "flag=
    set "found="

    REM Read each line from the file and process content when between searchString and endString
    for /f "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%a in ("%%f") do (
      if not defined found (
        echo %%a|findstr /ilbc:" COMPARE DIFFERENCE FOUND AT" >nul 2>&1 && (
            set "flag=1"
            echo %%~nxf, Failed
        )
        if defined flag if not defined found echo   %%a
        echo %%a|findstr /ilbc:" BOTTOM OF GOOD FILE" >nul 2>&1 && (
            set "flag="
            set "found=1"
        )    
      )
    )
    if not defined found echo %%~nxf, Passed
    echo\
))>"%outfile%"
```

NOTE: a `for /f` loop ignores empty lines and lines starting with `;`.
Also some "poison chars" in the file (like `|<>&!%` will make problems (syntax errors)
I didn't take care of that (for now) to keep it (relatively) simple for understanding.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I cannot get this to run, and I'm guessing it's because of the "poison chars" you mentioned above. How do I go about getting it so I can make it run, and is there a way to know when those "poison chars" will make syntax errors?

Comment: `I cannot get this to run` - what happens that shouldn't, what doesn't happen when it should, what errors do you get? How does your input file look like?) (a snippet of it (both the "needed" part and the "unwanted" part) would also be very helpful). We can't guess how it looks like. Don't try to put it into a comment, edit your question instead.

Comment: thanks for the response. Before I edit my post, I guess I should ask is the scripting you posted able to be run? I am unsure what the `echo %%a|findstr` is actually doing. When I say it doesn't work it just flashes on the screen and I don't see any of the messages.

Comment: Don't run per mouseclick. Open a `cmd` window and run it manually from there. Then the window will stay open and you can read any messages. `echo %%a|findstr`  pipes the output of `echo %%a` (the currently processed line) to `findstr`, to look whether it contains the string.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the help by @Stephan, the following code searches loops through all of my sub-directories and searches for a specific string of text in any .diff file. Once it finds the specific string, it prints to a consolidated output file starting at the found line to a second defined string.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
SET folderPath=%~dp0

REM Set the path for the output file to save the result
SET "outputFile=%folderPath%ValidationSummary.csv"
SET "output_fail=%folderPath%Validation_Fail.out"

REM Clear output file for first run
ECHO Run Name, Status > "%outputFile%"
TYPE NUL > "%output_fail%"

FOR /r "%folderPath%" %%f in (*.diff) do (
    REM Initialize variables
    set "flag="
    set "found="

    REM Read each line from the file and process content when between searchString and endString
    for /f "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%a in ("%%f") do (
      if not defined found (
        echo %%a|findstr /ilbc:" COMPARE DIFFERENCE FOUND AT" >nul 2>&1 && (
            set "flag=1"
REM            echo %%~nxf, Failed >> "%outputFile%"
        echo  >> "%output_fail%"
        echo %%~nxf Summary >> "%output_fail%"
        echo  >> "%output_fail%"
        )
        if defined flag if not defined found (echo %%a >> "%output_fail%")
        echo %%a|findstr /ilbc:" BOTTOM OF GOOD FILE" >nul 2>&1 && (
            set "flag="
            set "found=1"
        )    
      )
    )
    if not defined found (echo %%~nxf, Passed)
    echo\
)
```